# Thread safety with TaskCompletionSource.SetResult

Tags: c#, multithreading, asynchronous, async-await

Is it safe to pass non-thread-safe objects created on one thread to another using TaskCompletionSource.SetResult()?

e.g. in this contrived example:

```
using System;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class Test
{
    struct Info
    {
        public bool done;
        public Dictionary<int, int> results;
    }

    public static void Main()
    {
        WaitForIt();
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    static async void WaitForIt()
    {
        TaskCompletionSource<Info> myTcs = new TaskCompletionSource<Info>();

        Thread newThread = new Thread(new ParameterizedThreadStart(BackgroundThread));
        newThread.Start(myTcs);

        Info theInfo = await myTcs.Task;

        Console.WriteLine(theInfo.done);
        foreach (KeyValuePair<int, int> item in theInfo.results)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(item.Key + "=" + item.Value);
        }
    }

    static void BackgroundThread(object tcs)
    {
        TaskCompletionSource<Info> theTcs = (TaskCompletionSource<Info>)tcs;

        Info info = new Info();
        info.done = true;
        info.results = new Dictionary<int, int>();
        info.results.Add(1, 2);
        info.results.Add(3, 4);

        theTcs.SetResult(info);
    }
}
```

As the Info and Dictionary objects are created on one thread, passed to another thread, and never accessed again on the creating thread, there seems no need to perform any locking. The objects will never be accessed by multiple threads simultaneously.

Is a memory barrier required?

Is the reading thread guaranteed to have exactly the same data as the creating thread passed to SetResult()?

Comment: That depends on the particular object. Some objects may use Thread Local Storage or require thread affinity. With your particular code sample, it's fine, but keep in mind that structs are copied by value and normally should be immutable (have `readonly` fields). Say, if you do `theTcs.Task.Result.done = false`, the original `info.done` will remain `true`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it safe to pass non-thread-safe objects created on one thread to another using TaskCompletionSource.SetResult()?

Yes, as long as the object can be used on a different thread than the one it was created on (of course).

> Is a memory barrier required?

Nope. The `await` in the receiving thread will take care of that for you.

---

I must point out, though, that the use of `Thread` reads more like code from 1990 than it does from 2015. You should really use `Task.Run` instead. And since `Task.Run` understands result types already, there's no use for `TaskCompletionSource<T>` at all. Oh, and you should avoid `async void`:

```
public static void Main()
{
  WaitForItAsync().Wait();
  Console.ReadLine();
}

static async Task WaitForItAsync()
{
  Info theInfo = await Task.Run(() => CreateInfo());

  Console.WriteLine(theInfo.done);
  foreach (KeyValuePair<int, int> item in theInfo.results)
  {
    Console.WriteLine(item.Key + "=" + item.Value);
  }
}

static Info CreateInfo()
{
  Info info = new Info();
  info.done = true;
  info.results = new Dictionary<int, int>();
  info.results.Add(1, 2);
  info.results.Add(3, 4);
  return info;
}
```